# Discrete rational rotations on the two dimensional torus

Tags: dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

It is well known (Kronecker's Theorem) that "irrational rotations" are dense on $[0,1)$. That is, the set
$$
\{ x+nr\mod 1 :  n \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
is dense on $[0,1)$, provided that $r$ is irrational. This theorem is relatively easy to prove.

On the two dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}=[0,1)\times[0,1)$ (with opposite edges identified), the following result is true. The set
$$
\{ (x+nr \mod 1,x+nr' \mod 1) \in  \mathbb{T} : n \in \mathbb{N}
\}
$$
is dense in $\mathbb{T}$ if and only if $\{r, r', 1\}$ are rationally independent (i.e., if there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ar+br'$ is an integer, then $a=b=0$). I have seen a very complicated proof of this. Is there an "easy" proof? That is, something that one could assign for reading to an undergraduate (say a senior)?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a IMHO more appropriate tag. I have only seen this result in number-theoretic contexts. Actually I'm a bit curious to see how this is used in dynamical systems!

Comment: @Jyrki: For a completely integrable Hamiltonian system, the Arnold–Liouville
theorem says that the phase space (of dim $2n$, say) is foliated into
invariant tori (of dim $n$) such that the motion on each torus is just
a straight line (in suitable coordinates). Whether such a trajectory
is periodic or fills the torus densely depends on the rational
depencence or independence of the components of the direction vector of
the line.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for that bit. Can't say I'm familiar  with the result, but at least I can sort of see what's going on there. But here it looks like "time" (or whatever is the parameter of the motion) is ticking in discrete steps?

Comment: @Jyrki: True... Let's put it this way then: translation on a torus is a simple example of a discrete-time dynamical system, and it's interesting as an illustration of what type of global behaviour that orbits can exhibit. See for example Section 1.2 in [Zehnder's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=qva7p5NCayUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Hans, I'm afraid I get a "no eBook available".

Comment: @Jyrki: Funny. I can preview almost the whole book here. However, I'm automatically redirected to books.google.se, so maybe the permissions depend on which country you're in?

Comment: @Hans, it may also be related to the fact that I will not allow google.analytics to set cookies on my computer.

Comment: @Jyrki: You'll have to borrow someone else's computer then. ;-) It's a really nice book, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen IMHO quite accessible proofs of this fact in number theory books. When I was an advanced high school kid (I had found my calling), I saw a proof of this with hints in Joe Roberts' lovely book, typeset in calligraphic font, *Elementary Number Theory - A Problem Oriented Approach*. IIRC I managed to follow the proof given there, but this was among the more taxing problems. As an undergraduate I had the pleasure of giving a talk about this at a seminar going through Apostol's *Modular Functions and Automorphic Forms in Number Theory*. It is in one of the late chapters, and I recall enjoying that chapter and the exercises therein immensely.

I don't know if this is helpful to you. This stuff is certainly not too demanding for an undergraduate in that it doesn't rely on any deep theory. But I wouldn't assign this to someone who hasn't shown a real interest in thinking things through for him/herself. You know your clients better.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. I saw the (difficult) proof of this in a dynamical systems book, that's why I tagged it so. I'll look up the books you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I proved it by first proving $1, r, r'$ must be rationally independent by pairs (consider the circles $x=0$ and $y=0$, and you first have to prove the continuous version of the theorem, which only requires $r$ and $r'$ to be rationally independent (without the $1$)). Then you only need to consider the case $r' = ar + b$ for rational $a, b$. In this case you can show there is a finite number of lines of the type $y = qx + c$, with rational $q$ and $c$, which include all points in the orbit.

If you do it for specific values, for example: $r = \pi, r' = \frac{\pi}4 + \frac35$, you'll get the idea.